# What bird(s) is this in this recording?

Tags: birds, bird-behaviour, bird-watching, bird-identification

I have been hearing these birds from around the start of July in Australia from my backyard (mid-winter) at 7am, 8am and 9am depending on the day and they go on for at least 1-2hours. What bird(s) is/are these, is this seasonal and will they stop chirping?
[recording 1:](https://cloud.poodll.com/local/cpapi/downloader.php?p=https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/poodll-audioprocessing-out/CP/30/localhostuser/recordmp3online.com/poodll/poodllfile5f03b163b326a1.mp3&n=poodllfile5f03b163b326a1.mp3)

[recording 2](https://cloud.poodll.com/local/cpapi/downloader.php?p=https://s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/poodll-audioprocessing-out/CP/30/localhostuser/recordmp3online.com/poodll/poodllfile5f03b2f13a3281.mp3&n=poodllfile5f03b2f13a3281.mp3)

Thanks

Comment: Having had a listen to both tracks I find it quite hard to tell anything about the birds. The first track has a lot of fore-ground noise and the second has almost no noise (on my system at least). Any chance of a description of the birds, and a better recording?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not Australian, but, after a bit of research, it sounds like common blackbirds to me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EPB4u-BfYFA